# Is there a way to display a node label at the top inside the node?

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape, cytoscape-web, dagre

I am creating a graph using cytoscape.js and I have compounded nodes which are inside the parent node. I would like to have the title of the main/parent node at the top of the node but inside the node. Is that possible in cytoscape?

I have tried using using halign and valign. Whenever I use top value, it shows outside the box.

Is there a extension or a plugin that lets us do it?

Example with child node: https://stackblitz.com/edit/cytoscape-call-method-child-efmbaj?file=src%2Fapp%2FstylesheetObject.ts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I understand is that you want to put the parent label inside the box above child? apologies if I'm wrong

[image]

If so, My solution will be to add a padding and then apply margin for alignment.

[Modified your example](https://cytoscape-call-method-child-ppbrfd.stackblitz.io/)

**Styles updated:**

1. **'padding-top':60**

   ```
   selector: 'node',
   css: {
     content: 'data(label)',
     'text-valign': 'center',
     'text-halign': 'center',
     'font-size': 28,
     'padding-top':60
   }
   ```
2. **'text-valign': 'top',** and '**text-margin-y': function(node) {
   return node.height() - 10;
   }**

   ```
   selector: 'node[type="parent"]',
   style: {
     shape: 'rectangle',
     'background-color': 'grey',
     width: 300,
     height: 100,
     'font-size': 25.5,
     'font-family': 'Lato, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
     color: 'black',
     'text-valign': 'top',
     'text-halign': 'center',
     'text-margin-y': function(node) {
       return node.height() - 10;
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: This is working. The only thing, when I add padding top it does not just add padding at the top, it adds padding everywhere and makes the node of different size. Do you know a way of adding a space at the top like a margin instead of padding?

Comment: Try adding 'padding-top' to specific selector like  'node[type="parent"]'

Comment: I am adding padding top to selector like 'node[type="parent"]'
It still adds padding everywhere so the node size increases

Answer (score 5):

As you can read [here](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/1370#issuecomment-218790661), you can only place labels inside a node with the center option, a good configuration (label inside at the top) requires a margin to be added to your label:

```js
.selector(':parent')
  .css({
    'text-valign': 'center',
    // the next line moves the parents label up to the top of the node and 5px down to create a padding 
    'text-margin-y': function (node) { return -node.height() + 5 }
})
```

Here is a working example:

```js
var cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),

  style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
    .selector(':parent')
    .css({
      'text-valign': 'center',
      'text-margin-y': function(node) {
        return -node.height() + 5
      }
    })
    .selector('node')
    .css({
      'height': 'data(size)',
      'width': 'data(size)',
      'border-color': '#000',
      'border-width': '1',
      'content': 'data(name)'
    })
    .selector('edge')
    .css({
      'width': 'data(strength)'
    })
    .selector('#1')
    .css({
      'background-color': 'red'
    })
    .selector('#4')
    .css({
      'background-color': 'green'
    }),

  elements: {
    nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: '1',
          size: 50,
          name: 'a'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: '2',
          size: 20,
          name: 'b',
          parent: '1'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: '3',
          size: 40,
          name: 'c',
          parent: '1'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: '4',
          size: 50,
          name: 'd'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: '5',
          size: 20,
          name: 'e',
          parent: '4'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: '6',
          size: 40,
          name: 'f',
          parent: '4'
        }
      }
    ],
  },
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 75%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.2.17/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is not working if you have a node inside a node. The child node does not go down and make space for the title. The title just goes behind the child node

Comment: Here is a simple example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/cytoscape-call-method-child-efmbaj?file=src%2Fapp%2FstylesheetObject.ts

Comment: If I set this ```{
    selector: 'node[type="parent"]',
    style: {
      shape: 'rectangle',
      'background-color': 'grey',
      width: 300,
      height: 100,
      'font-size': 25.5,
      'font-family': 'Lato, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
      color: 'black',
      'text-valign': 'top',
      'text-halign': 'center',
      'text-margin-y': function(node) {
        return '40px';
      }
    }
  },```
I see the labels are behind the child node

Comment: @canbax does this mean that this is not possible with cytoscape currently?

Comment: @LearnAspNet it might be impossible, not sure. I couldn't find a way. You might want to check issues in cytoscape.js repository. Also you might want to play with styles like `z-compound-depth` and `z-index`, `background-opacity`, `opacity` etc..

Logically if you want your child node to be visible, it should be rendered on top of its parent. So parent's z-index should be lower. So then its label should also be rendered before child. I think it is contradictory.

Comment: If z-index of parent is greater then you can not see its children